# GNOME Desktop does not appear after upgrading 32 bit system from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, gnome-shell

I upgraded my 32 bit system from 16.04 to 18.04. I expected to see the GNOME 3 Desktop. Instead I still see the Unity Desktop. Logging out and back in, there is no desktop selection option presented. I’ve tried installing GNOME 3 manually with no success. I’ve verified that GNOME 3 is installed. There are no desktop options available in the system settings. How can I setup my system to recognize the GNOME 3 Desktop as default and to switch between desktops?

Comment: The desktop selection option is on the Password screen (not the Username screen). If the selector really is not there, please take a clear photo of the password screen and post it in your question.

Comment: Is gdm3 installed as Display Manager, which is needed. Sounds like you're still running lightdm. To check, run `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.